# git rebase from master into feature branch PR shows all files changed

Tags: git, git-rebase

I was attempting to merge in master into my feature branch which I already had an open PR for in GitHub and I ran:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout my-branch
git rebase master
git add .
git commit -am "merge in master"
git push origin my-branch
```

However, after I pushed, now my PR shows ALL the files changed between my branch and master as if they in my branch (PR). How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us some relevant parts of the log? E.g. `git log --graph --decorate --oneline master my-branch`. I suspect `master` got rewritten, in which case you would have some duplicated/old commits in `my-branch`.

Comment: @alfunx here is the log, without the commit messages as they contained some company sensitive information. Not sure it will be helpful. https://gist.github.com/nodesocket/7eac8af29e494563e46360421edf129f

Comment: @Justin The merge commit `4ac203701` looks suspious. Looking at the last line, I'd say the second parent of that merge was branched off earlier from master. I don't know which branch you rebased onto which one, so I can't tell much more so far, other than that you should inspect that merge.

Comment: @alfunx ok, I tried running `git revert 4ac203701` but getting `error: commit 4ac20370180d0e1fed3ea99b95679ab4e878e110 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed`

Comment: Well, revert wouldn't have been the right solution either. What I meant is that you should inspect the merge commit (e.g. with `git show` or `git diff`) to make sure it didn't introduce anything unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to close the PR in GitHub, and delete the `my-feature` branch **only in GitHub**. Then locally I simply did `git push origin my-feature` and created a new PR in GitHub.